# How to start new relic tool for a service which is running in tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, server, newrelic

I need to add NewRelic java agent to a service which is running in tomcat server.
What are the steps for it.
Do I need to write any separate script for starting the newRelic for that service?
Or do I need to modify calatina.sh file so that along with tomcat server starting,newrelic tool will also get started.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need any separate script - the agent will start when your Tomcat service starts. Here's how installation works:

1. [Get the agent](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/installation/install-java-agent#download-agent)
2. [Set your license key](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/installation/install-java-agent#config-file) in newrelic.yml
3. [Configure your catalina.sh](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/installation/include-java-agent-jvm-argument#Installing_on_Tomcat) to use the New Relic Java agent using `JAVA_OPTS` - here is an example of mine, just added to the top of the catalina.sh file: `export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/tomcat/newrelic/newrelic.jar"`
4. You should also [set the services name](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/configuration/name-your-java-application#naming-options). Restart your Tomcat service and view the app in New Relic

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did the above steps .My catalina.sh is located in /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh. I need to add that line[export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/tomcat/newrelic/newrelic.jar"] in that file and copy it back to that location[/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh].While doing this, docker image got created succesfullly.But while building the container its crashing. I simply tried copying that catalina.sh file to some other location.It allowed. But to that location[/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh] it is throwing error.